# Vb.net HTMLAgilityPack Loop for Each Row

Tags: vb.net, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

When scraping from a web browser control I can use something like:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.Bookie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
    If element.GetAttribute("className") = "name" Then
        'do whatever here
    End If
Next
```

Which works fine.

It loops for every TR and if it finds the "name" class it does what I need.

Trying to do it with sockets and HTMLAgilityPack is causing some problems. I can't simply use:

```
SelectNodes("//tr[@class='name']")
```

Because the agility pack is changing the format and removing my line breaks making parsing impossible. The data is there and it reads it but HTMLAgilityPack does things a little different to the browser control sometimes.

So instead I need to loop for every tr and check to see if other classes exist for each one. They're not always there and I need to know when they're not so again just doing a SelectNodes("//tr[@class='otherclass']") isn't enough. I need to know if the TR has it.

So I'd like it to loop for every tr and proc if it finds a classname "otherclass" within that tr.

I'm assuming it's possible but I'm not sure what the syntax would look like.

I've tried variations on:

```
For Each node As HtmlNode In SmarkDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")
    For Each SecondNode As HtmlNode In node.SelectNodes("//a[@class='otherclass']")
        'do whatever
    Next
Next
```

The nested loop I tried to use node.selectnodes from the first //tr loop but it just loops over all the HTML. So I'm assuming it's either a problem with my syntax on the second loop causing it to look at all of the HTML and basically ignoring the first loop or something with the xpath in the second loop.

I know there's a difference there with the 'a' tag but the browser didn't need it while xpath does.

I'm assuming (and very much hoping) there's something I could do like:

```
For Each node As HtmlNode In SmarkDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")
    If node.Element.Contains("otherclass") Then
        'proc for each name
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `For Each SecondNode As HtmlNode In node.SelectNodes("//a[@class='otherclass']")` to `For Each SecondNode As HtmlNode In node.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='otherclass']")` then your inner `For Each` processes the descendant `a` elements and not all `a` elements.

Comment: Aah because it should be relative not absolute. I was looking at that but my xpath is pretty weak and I thought pointing it at the first node would sort that.

Comment: I upvoted but it doesn't show because I don't have rep yet. Thanks a lot Martin really appreciated.